# password confirmation through email using php in WAMP

Tags: php, mysqli, wamp

At the time of login, the details of the user are taken into the database but no email gets sent for activation of account. It shows the following error:
done:

```
( ! ) Warning: mail() [<a href='function.mail'>function.mail</a>]: Failed to connect to mailserver at &quot;mail.YourDomain.com&quot; port 25, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp\www\form\index2.php on line 61
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  385856  {main}( )   ..\index2.php:0
2   0.0078  398648  mail ( )    ..\index2.php:61
Thank you for registering! A confirmation email has been sent to divschari@gmail.com Please click on the Activation Link to Activate your account
```

The code for activating the account is:

```
    if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1) { //If the Insert Query was successfull.

                // Send the email:
                $message = " To activate your account, please click on this link:\n\n";
                $message .=WEBSITE_URL .'activate.php?email='. urlencode($Email) . "&key=$activation";

                mail($Email, 'Registration Confirmation', $message, 'From:'.EMAIL);

                // Flush the buffered output.

                // Finish the page:
                echo '<div class="success">Thank you for
registering! A confirmation email
has been sent to ' . $Email .
                    ' Please click on the Activation Link to Activate your account </div>';

            } else { // If it did not run OK.
                echo '<div class="errormsgbox">You could not be registered due to a system
error. We apologize for any
inconvenience.</div>';
            }

        } else { // The email address is not available.
            echo '<div class="errormsgbox" >That email
address has already been registered.
</div>';
        }
```

Changes to php.ini were made but the error in the code persists.

Comment: you have to configure your smtp mail server in wamp, set its username, password , port, smtp provider. after that you can send mail from wamp local server.

Comment: Already tried downloading sendmail.zip from Fake Sendmail. But the downloaded files are corrupted. Any other way to set up SMTP?

Comment: Yes, use gmail's smtp. Pass its username, password, port, and smtp host. You will find some example on google.

Comment: if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1) { 
                $message = " To activate your account, please click on this link:\n\n";
                $message .=WEBSITE_URL .'activate.php?email='. urlencode($Email) . "&key=$activation";
               
    mail($Email, 'Registration Confirmation', $message, 'From:'.EMAIL);
 
                               
                echo '<div class="success">Thank you for
registering! A confirmation email
has been sent to ' . $Email .
                    ' Please click on the Activation Link to Activate your account </div>';

Comment: I got the sendmail.ini file ,made changes to it and php.ini. When i run the code it produces the activation key but doesnot send the email to the desired destination.